# using cin to read input of ints separated by spaces

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I'm a beginner in C++ and just starting out.

I want to read a line of integers separated by spaces using `cin`, store them, and process them, let's say by multiplying each integer by 2.

The input would be:

```
1 2 3 4
```

and its output would be:

```
2 4 6 8
```

I would like the program to execute immediately after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You should write an actual program that tries to do this, and then have that as part of your question so that we can examine what you are having difficulties with. It's not our job to write programs for you.

Comment: sorry, but reading space seperated values is kind of the most basic thing you can do with `std::cin`. Any tutorial on reading input should cover this (or it is crap)

Comment: @brothir its also not our job to answer well written questions. If I read between the lines I completely agree with you, though recently being nice is rather high valued ;)

Comment: @eclipse if you want a less advanced answer you will have to add your non code (yes we expect it to be non-working). The current answer shows some of the advantages of modern `c++` (c++11 - 2011 standard) but that probably will not help a person who is just beginning.

Comment: @Eclipse, the simple technique is to read your line of numbers into a string using `std::getline` then read the numbers from that string using `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Sounds like you should search the internet before posting.  Search for "stackoverflow c++ read space separated".  There are already a plethora of CSV related questions.

Comment: @john it would be simpler to just use `operator>>` directly on `std::cin`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How then would the OP know where the line ended? The point of the question is that they want to read a single line

Answer (score 4):

Simple `for` loop and storing values in `vector` will do the job for you;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    std::string input;

    getline(cin, input); // get input until newline

    istringstream sstr(input);
    int ele;

    while (sstr >> ele) {
       vec.push_back(ele);
    }

    transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [](int x) {
        return 2 * x;
    });

    for (const auto &ele: vec) {
        cout << ele << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

As rightly suggested by [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin), you may combine `transform` and `for` loop to a single line by `std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), [](int x) { return 2 * x; });`

Don't forget to include `iterator` header file for it.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin. I have included your point in the answer.

Comment: Or: `std::transform(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {}, [](int x) { return 2 * x; }, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));` and skip both loops and the vector

Comment: @Caleth: That no longer meets the specs--it'll continue reading input until the user signals EOF on input, rather than running as soon as they press `enter`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree with your point.

Comment: The code is even simpler if you don't use a vector. Just read a value, display the result, continue until done.

Comment: @PeteBecker As Jerry Coffin rightly said, it won't work according to the spec as mentioned by OP.

Comment: @KunalPuri Sure, it doesn't match the OP requirements which are to read a single line. You even seem to agree with this above.

Comment: @john That agreement about which you are talking about was for the suggestion which was given by Caleth. Just for the case of simplicity, I am getting number of elements `n` from the user. This is a generally followed convention which is even used in coding challenges.

Comment: @john I agreed to JerryCoffin's comment because OP specifically mentioned reading, storing and processing in the question which I think Caleth's suggestion was not satisfying.

Comment: @KunalPuri I think JerryCoffin's point is the same as mine. Your code does not stop reading after a single line, it keeps going until end of file. Since this seems to be the main point of the OP's question I down voted.

Comment: @john I updated my answer. Thanks for your suggestion.